# Divine Metamagic -- do you need the base metamagic feat in a feat slot already?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, divine, metamagic

When applying Divine Metamagic to a metamagic feat -- by RAW, do you need to have the base metamagic feat in a feat slot and *then* use a second feat slot to apply Divine Metamagic to it, or does the combination of Divine Metamagic and the base metamagic feat take up a single feat slot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to have both the regular metamagic feat *and* Divine Metamagic

> When you take this feat, choose a metamagic feat **that you have.** This feat applies **only to that metamagic feat.**

Comment: It’s worth noting that the first bolded section was added by [errata](http://www.robsworld.org/dndcampaign/3.5%20Errata/CompDiv_Errata09102004.pdf).